# why is the onclick event not working in javascript when the button and function reference both show the right objects?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm setting up a simple game of battleship that would take a user input and compare it to ship locations but for some reason the onclick method won't work when the button is clicked on the html end. there are no errors in console and when I've added console.log(firebutton) it pulls up the right html object and when I've done Console.log(fireButton.OnClick) it is referencing the function not a result of the function. I'm stuck and can't see why the onClick method wont run the function when the button is clicked. I can call the controllers process guess method directly in the init function and it works fine but when I try to do it through the user input nothing happens.

my code:

```js
function init() {
  var fireButton = document.getElementById("fireButton");
  fireButton.onclick = handleFireButton; // editor lowercased onclick

}

function handleFireButton() {
  var guessInput = document.getElementById("guessInput");
  var guess = guessInput.value;
  controller.processGuess(guess);
  guessInput.value = "";
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="guessInput" placeholder="A0">
  <input type="button" id="fireButton" value="Fire!">
</form>
```

Comment: JS is case-sensitive, should be onclick.

Comment: That was a bit unexpected response, maybe it was meant to some other thread ..?

Comment: You are missing the controller in the snippet I made you. I lowercased the onclick for you